# does ambari use nagios

Tags: monitoring, nagios, ambari

I'm newbie to ambari,so I'm reading some articles about it
in [one](http://blog.octo.com/ambari-la-supervision-de-cluster-hadoop/) of these articles it's said that :

> ambari dashboard is used to give information issued from Ganglia and Nagios

so I wonder if ambari use, or based on Nagios to monitor it's services, if not does it possible to use nagios to monitor ambari (and it's services ) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nagios and Ganglia were used as standalone services, to provide info for Ambari 1.7.0 and less. Since version 2.0, Ambari moved to use his own monitoring service **Ambari Metrics** and **Ambari Alerts**. Support of Nagios with Ganglia was dropped.